# Remove white space between <h2> border and content

Tags: html, css

Let's consider this simple code:

**HTML**

```html
 <h2>Some text</h2>
```

When rendered, a white space between the *h2* upper/lower borders and the upper/lower borders of the text shows. Is there a way to remove this white space?

I've been able to achieve that giving a fixed value to the *line-height* property; however, this solution seems to me me a bit too 'forced'. How can I achieve the same in a more 'natural' way?

Comment: Remove the margin

Comment: Headings have margins by default. Do `<h2 style="margin: 0;">`, or just do it in CSS `h2 { margin: 0; }`

Comment: Or use a standard CSS Reset...

Answer (score 3):

You can set `margin` and `padding` to `0`. I put the `h2` into a `div` so that it is easier to see the difference.

```css
h2.remove-whitespace {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 25px;
}

div {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!-- with margin:0;padding:0 -->
<div>
    <h2 class="remove-whitespace">Some text</h2>
</div>

<!-- original -->
<div>
    <h2>Some text</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Sumner.

I already tried to set margin and padding to 0, but some white space is still there (as shown in your code snippet, too). What I'm trying to achieve is letting the upper/lower borders of the h2 tag adhere perfectly to the upper/lower borders of the text without that 'extra' white space.

Comment: @GiS91, I made it a little better by manually editing the `line-height` and `height`, but it will probably never be perfect since the font itself has inherent whitespace.

Comment: Uhmm... what I thought: it's a question of inherent font whitespace. To your knowledge, is there a way to remove this 'type' of white space other than the 'line-height' hack? 

To make it clear: line-height works perfectly but, as stated previously, this solution seems to me a bit too 'forced'.

Answer (score 2):

this one will do.

```
<h2 style="margin:0">Some text<h2>
```

but for best practice, always use put all your css code in an external css file or in your html file within style tags in `head` tag.

in your external css file

```
h2{
    margin:0;
}
```

or in your html file itself

put the code in `head` tag

```
<style>
    h2{
          margin:0;
    }
</style>
```

Please read this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Whilst this is the simplest solution, it is always advisable to avoid inline-css where possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Aman. I already tried to set margin (and padding) to 0, but some white space is still there. What I'm trying to achieve is letting the upper/lower borders of the h2 tag adhere perfectly to the upper/lower borders of the text without that 'extra' white space.

Comment: @GiS91 try this:  `html, body, h2 { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by removing the margin from the H2 element using css.

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
 <h2>Some text</h2>
```

If you only want to remove the space from the top or bottom of the `<h2>` element you can use the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

html's heading elements (e.g h1....hx) has a predetermined padding and margin. To test, you can add a border to the heading elements using css, but thats not the case here. So just set the padding and marging to **0** and it would work fine, but remember it woun't change the font-size.

Answer (score 0):

This comes under the default styles when the page is rendered. you will face this issue with all the HTML tags.

Please use [reset.css](http://cssreset.com/scripts/html5-doctor-css-reset-stylesheet/) to overcome all the tag default style issues.

enjoy styling!! :D